# Cannot access disposed object application connecting to WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin

I have content of video and object being created an pass into a http client web api. When ever I pass the image to the client it works find it gets to the post method, but when it comes to the video the client has trouble posting the video. I checked the video size length to make sure it meets the content length and it well under the specific ranges. The error that I receive is that the object has been disposed. If you look at the code the object is never disposed. 
Here's the code on the app

```
public async Task<bool> AddToQueueAsync(Incident i, ContentPage page, MediaFile file)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    Uri webserviceURL = i.IncidentType == IncidentType.Trooper ? trooperURL : gspURL;
    var fileStream = File.Open(file.Path, FileMode.Open);

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
             using (fileStream)
             {
                 using (var stream = new StreamContent(fileStream))
                 {
                     using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("----MyBoundary"))
                     {
                         if(i.MediaType == "Video")
                         {
                             content.Add(stream,"file", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".mp4");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             content.Add(stream, "file", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png");
                         }
                         content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i)), "metadata");

                         result = await client.PostAsync(webserviceURL, content);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
```

Here is the code on the web api:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult StarGSPDATA() {
        try {
            if(!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) {
                Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            starGSPDATAinfo suspicousInfo;
            string homeDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string dir = $"{homeDir}/uploads/";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

            if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Count > 0) {
                suspicousInfo = MetaDataFromRequest(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form);
            } else {
                suspicousInfo = new starGSPDATAinfo();
            }

            if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);

                suspicousInfo.MediaFilePath = fileName;

                try {
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"not saving: {e.ToString()}");
                }
            } else {
                throw new HttpResponseException(
                    new HttpResponseMessage(
                        HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
            }

            CleanData(suspicousInfo);

            db.starGSPDATAinfoes.Add(suspicousInfo);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Created("http://localhost:50641/api/StarGSPDATA/", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(suspicousInfo));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
```

It works for an image but not for a video Please help thank you!

[Here is a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiFlH.png)

Comment: (1) Does the error occur in the client or the sever and (2) what line number does the error occur on?  I'd be interested in knowing where/how `db` is declared.

Comment: Your code would be much more readable if you stacked your using statements and didn't indent each using block. The curly braces are only necessary for the innermost using statement.

Comment: ok i will change that

Comment: Paul i will post the db solution

Comment: right now i am using localhost

Comment: The error occurs result = await client.PostAsync(webserviceURL, content); it throws an exception stating cannot acces dispose item